# "ng add" results in error "The file (./src/ts) does not exist."

Tags: angular

### I am trying to install Angular Universal from `@ng-toolkit`

`ng add @ng-toolkit/universal`

### but i get the error

> INFO: Project property is set to 'fornida-ng6'.
>   ERROR: The file (./src/ts) does not exist.`

[image]

### Repo

https://github.com/ohabash/fornida-ng6/

Is this a `ng add` issue or is it with toolkit. How can i debug?

Comment: Check `https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen`

Comment: ive been all over these issues. Anything particular?

Comment: try running
`npm run -- ng add...`
It will use local angular version. The CLI has problems between versions. Alternatively update to latest version in that repo